# How can we store a dynamic value in Tosca?

Tags: tosca

I am working on Tricenties Tosca Tool. I need to overcome one challenge of storing dynamic values. 
Scenario is:

I am working on healthcare domain project and we have to do registration of a patient. Once all the details of the patients are filled and we confirm then its generating the Medical Record Number (MRN). This MRN is dynamic and unique for every patient. This MRN number is also used in other flow.So my challenge is how can I store this Dynamic number.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can store it in a so called Buffer. Find all about it here: https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=13.0.0&url=articles/buffer_this.htm

Comment: One benefit of buffers is that they persist across tests, and even reboots.

Answer (score 0):

The below is the format is use to capture and maybe use later in the test.

`{XB[Valuename]}`